# Proving of an E.G.F

Tags: exponential-function, oeis

We wish to prove that the exponential generating function of the sequence defined by the recurrence relations $$a_0 = 1, a_1 = 1$$ $$a_n = na_{n-1} + (n-1)a_{n-2}$$ is given by $\frac{e^{-x} }{(1-x)^2}$

We came across this series in the context of some research and wish to compute the e.g.f via the method of Taylor series.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have edited the question with mathjax to make it more readable. Please verify that this is what you wanted

Comment: yes that's what we're actually looking for. it's my first time asking for help in this site that why i am not that familiar with the best way to express some questions. thankyouu so much

Answer (score 0):

I try to prove the e.g.f using the Taylor series as it requires, is this correct?

```
[![proving of the e.g.f][1]][1]
```